# Github repo deployment Issue. 1.Pages build and deployement is failure

Tags: github-pages

Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
Setting up auth for fetching submodules
Fetching submodules
/usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive

Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Rating_Card' in .gitmodules

Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128

Not getting Live URL of the pages.